# Transitioning a storyboard from just Auto Layout to Size Classes

Tags: ios, storyboard, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint, size-classes

As I say in the title, I have a `storyboard` where I only use `Auto Layout`. It was developed for `iOS 7` Deployment Target and now I'd like to make some updates and set it to `iOS 8`. I currently handle devices orientation changes in UI and different `iPhone` screen sizes by setting the alternative `NSLayoutConstraint` in each scene's `UIViewController` implementation, which was a pain... as far as I know, taking advantage of `Size Classes` makes this much easier.

I have quite a lot of scenes in my `storyboard`, so before enabling `Size Classes` I'd want to know if I'd be able to keep a "mix": I mean, if I enable `Size Classes` in the `storyboard`, will I have to use it in all its scenes? Or could I keep them the way they currently are, and then start doing partial migrations without "breaking" the app?

Another final question: is there something upcoming in `iOS 9` regarding this that would be recommended right now to be taken into account?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This shouldn't present any issues, however version control is your best friend for situations like this. I would make a branch in your git repo and test first if you're not convinced.

**Size classes** works with **auto layout**. Think of it as though your current story board only supports one *device family* that all constraints are managed through. When enabling **size classes** for the story board it now supports multiple *device families* for constraint management.

When you enable **size classes** for your story board all constraints will default to the *device family* of **any size** and **any width** (which could be thought of as *device family all*). You can then go about refactoring existing logic in your code to be managed by **size classes** in you story board by adding new, and altering existing constraints in interface builder for additional *device families*, then removing the redundant code. An example of an additional *device family* could be **regular width** and **compact height** (which is currently an iPhone 6 plus only).

Comment: Thanks! The point is: could I deliver an app having the scenes of the storyboard partially migrated to size classes? Or will I have to wait until I have migrated all the scenes in it?